# Using AWS Code Commit with Microsoft AD as Federation Provider and across multiple AWS Accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I am trying to create a POC to leverage Code Commit. I have 2 constraints so was wondering if it is a liable option.

**Constraint#1** - When I login to AWS account, I see 3 Accounts for Dev, QA and Prod. Is there a way to access Repo cross accounts 
[image]

**Constraint#2** - I am logging into AWS console using corporate credentials.So using federated Identities [AD FS]

Can I still leverage CodeCommit considering these 2 constraints?

Comment: Generally you use [cross-account roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/cross-account.html) to work with CC in different account. It does not matter if you use federated identities or not, as long as they can assume the role enabling the cross account access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use AWS SSO service (which connects to your MS AD), it is easy to obtain credentials for cli. Please have a look at this blog post:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-federated-identities-with-aws-codecommit/